# Can I train a network to get the output for the other network?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's assume there are two networks called A and B.
I want to train the network A to get the output which is also the input of network B. 
Network B can be considered as a trained network by other people. My work is to train the network A and the weights of network B would be fixed.
Can it work?

Comment: Yes that definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

It surely works, you just don't apply backpropagation to the weights of B.